# Restful NodeJs can't load database Mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was build new project with NodeJs. I got this code from youtube channel and its been uploaded 2 years ago. when I trying to practice I got some error. my database cant load and always show "No Comic Here".

this my index.js code:

````
```    /*
    
    
    
    */
    
    var express = require('express');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    
    //
    var connnect=mysql.createConnection
    ({  host:'localhost',
        user:'root',
        password:'',
        database:'testmanga'
    });
    
    //
    var app=express();
    var publicDir=(__dirname+/'public'/);
    app.use(express.static(publicDir));
    
    //
    app.get("/banner",(req,res,next)=>{
        connnect.query('SELECT * FROM banner',function(error,result,fields){
            connnect.on('error',function(err) {
                console.log('[MY SQL ERROR]', err);
            });
    
            if (result && result.lenght)
                {
                    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
                } 
                else
                {
                    res.end(JSON.stringify("No Comic Here"));
                }
        })
    });
    
    //
    app.get("/comic",(req,res,next)=>{
        connnect.query('SELECT * FROM manga',function(error,result,fields){
            connnect.on('error',function(err) {
                console.log('[MY SQL ERROR]', err);
            });
    
            if (result && result.lenght)
                {
                    res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
                } 
                else
                {
                    res.end(JSON.stringify("No Comic Here"));
                }
        })
    });
    
    //
    app.listen(3000, ()=>{
        console.log("you're connected to port 3000");
    })```
````

I've been trying for changing **localhost** to **127.0.0.1**, but still no working.

Comment: Run the sql würd on terminal and Look for the content kn the database.

Comment: `result && result.lenght` will always fail because it's `result.length`. Also, you can simply do `res.json(result);`

Comment: @ChrisG ahh I see, my bad. its look like not different, solved. thanks

Comment: Great, feel free to save the mods some time and delete this question yourself :)